# Sitecore - Manually copy indexes, do you need to restart app pool

Tags: iis, sitecore, lucene

The company I'm working for like to manually rebuild the Lucene indexes using the /admin/toolbox/rebuild-index.aspx in Sitecore 6.6. Once they have been rebuilt they then copy the files to each Content Delivery server manually and then restart the app pool on each CD server.

At the moment due to the way the site was built, the site has a long start-up time (this is being fixed sometime in the future) so the restarting of the app pools is a pain. My question is:

Does one need to restart the app pools for the new index files to be picked up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Files will be locked by Lucene when it's running.

I guess, theoretically, it would be possible to get Lucene running on the CD servers in a read-only mode - but I've never attempted this myself, and don't know of a way to achieve it off hand.

If you are going to be doing fixes on the site in the future, might I suggest you move the indexing off server?   Implement a SOLR centralised index.  That way, when rebuilt, it will be readily available to any and all CD servers right away, with no need for copying and/or restarting app pools.

Comment: I've already suggested a SOLR server, the company I'm working for wasn't very receptive.

Comment: Ok. Well given you have multiple CD servers, I am guessing you're dealing with sites under considerable load. If that is the case, there's good value in setting up a SOLR to serve them - it can be a reasonably cheap box, and it will free up a very significant amount of CPU load on the CD servers by them not having to deal with index lookups. I don't have an exact number, but I would not be surprised if the capacity of each CD server increases by 20% or more. Then it becomes a matter of simple economics ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Scalability settings may be somethkng you need for multiple server implementation.

Does this cover lucene is something you may need to find out.

Comment: This does not answer the question, I've read both Sitecore Scaling Guide and the Sitecore Search and Indexing document, neither answer the question above.